# Which package to choose for a bug report about annoying beeps during BIOS update?

Tags: updates, uefi, bios, bug-reporting

So far, I installed two BIOS updates from within Ubuntu 18.10 for a Lenovo ThinkPad T480 which worked great (awesome that this is now supported by Ubuntu).

However, during the update the laptop beeps about every two seconds. It takes about 5 minutes and is similar to a bomb countdown in an action movie.

I'm starting the update by clicking on ~"Install" in the "Updates" tab of a popped up Software Center instance and rebooting.

Which one is the correct package to report this issue to?

Comment: I believe you are looking for the package `fwupd` which is used by `gnome-software` or `discover`. I could imagine that the beeps are just a warning that an update is currently performed and one shouldn't switch of power until the update is ready.

Answer (score 0):

Against the package containing the tool you used. Which one ?

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Comment: Reporting a bug in/suggesting an improvement to a BIOS update against `ubuntu-software` doesn't sound right.

Comment: That's not what he asked ;) You use a tool to update bios. But I would assume this will be out of scope for Ubuntu: it is 3rd party. And those beeps are intentional: normally those beeps indicate a problem.

Comment: @Rinzwind I added an explanation that I'm initiating the BIOS update through Software Center to the question. Your guess that it's out-of-scope is probably right, however I have a dualboot setup with Windows 10 and I did BIOS updates from Windows and from Ubuntu and only the Ubuntu updates beep. I'd be surprised if it was a feedback beep, since it's a repeating beep every second for 4 minutes - except that a very annoying and threatening permanent sound indicates that the update is still in progress.